Dynamo Pulumi setup not accepting L list data type
I am attempting to set up a DynamoDB table via Pulumi and thought everything was fine after reviewing official documentation, however I am getting a warning message about my data type not being valid.

error: aws:dynamodb/table:Table resource 'table-name' has a problem: expected type to be one of ["S" "N" "B"], got L. Examine values at 'table-name.attributes'.

I am wanting to use a List data type to hold my array of values as I had seen through official docs.
Is there any reason why I would be getting a message like this? Is it a general issue, or could it be something specific/an arbitrary rule within my own pipeline I'm unaware of?
const tableName = `table-name`;
  const dynamoDbTable = new DynamoDBTable(tableName, {
    name: tableName,
    hashKey: "ID",
    attributes: [
      {
        name: "ID",
        type: "S",
      },
      ...
      {
        name: "RESULTS",
        type: "L"
      }
    ],
    ...
  });


Pulumi is used to create Infrastructure as Code (IaC). When creating DynamoDB tables, you never declare non-key attributes as DynamoDB is schemaless.
As you only declare key attributes, they must conform to DynamoDB's rules that they should be a scalar data type of either String S, Number N or Binary B.
This is why you get the exception. I assume RESULTS is not a key attribute, you should remove it from your table creation code.

How do you define what a "key attribute" is? ID is the primary key that data will be stored against, and I'm wanting to store a number of attributes that are strings and numbers, then this list of results... Are you saying that I should only be defining ID in the attributes? If so... when the DB is provisioned by Pulumi, will I actually be able to push those pieces of data (strings, numbers and the List) like I'm planning to?

Yes, with DynamoDB you only provide the partition key (and optional sort key) at creation time. Your other attributes which will exist within the item can be added when you add data. Each item must contain partition key (and sort key if you defined one). There is no defined schmea, i.e: schemaless
